# Packaging Flash Builder Apps for Android/IOS - assets directory Q

Tags: android, air, directory, adobe, packaging

First timer here.

I've been writing an app that's intended to be deployed onto mobile platforms (iOS and Android ). This uses Flash Builder 4.6's android build target - it uses a subdirectory in the /assets/ directory, that contains an arbitrary number of .png files.

I code a directory loader as such:

```
public function LoadFromDirectory(directoryName:String, store:Vector.<BitmapData>):Boolean
{
    //Changed here: this should work on both the development environment, AND the device.  
    //Guess what...

    imageDirectory = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("assets/" +directoryString);

    //This is triggering on Android. Doesn't do so in ADL. Not tested on iOS yet, 
    //but come on, if it doesn't work here, it won't work on iOS...

    if (!imageDirectory.isDirectory) 
    { 
        trace("Directory not found:" +imageDirectory.url);
        return false;
    }

    /*Snip loop through the contents of this directory, loading anything that is
    a PNG and storing the bitmapData of all loaded PNGs into the vector, one by one*/

   /*This of course, ALL works in ADL*/
}
```

This works in the air virtual devices, but isn't working on the mobile devices or on deployment. This is where I'm stuck.

Edit: Ok, I've gone and reduced the File code to just one line. I should be using resolvePath for cross-platform compatibility; also, the packager from Flash Builder doesn't see the "assets\" subdirectory unless I put it inside "bin-debug\", because that's where the compiled SWF went.

Still doesn't solve the problem tho - at least for the Android build, I can see the assets folder in the apk (by renaming it to a .zip and extracting it all), and it's the correct one (alongside the app's XML files and the SWF).

The apk installs and runs, but isDirectory still returns false when I debug on the device itself (once again, not on ADL - on the device only). Commenting that entire if...segment will crash the app instead because well, it can't find the assets\ directory.

I'm this close to solving the problem; would appreciate if someone helped me with the final step, because it's taking bloody ages to figure out.

PS: I would love to simply just embed the images in a FLA or SWC which I've done before and it works. Unfortunately, the number and name of images in that particular directory is *arbitrary*; the only thing that I'm certain of is the supported extensions.

PPS: Usage of this function: LoadImagesFromDirectory("imagesdirectory"), which should look under app:/assets/imagesdirectory in any platform. The Boolean return is for debugging (returns false if a directory with that name doesn't exist.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

...alright, I don't know if this is documented, but apparently I was calling LoadImagesFromDirectory to a directory name that is all caps, because on the PC, the target directory was also in all caps.

So in the test platform, the directory resolved to "app:/assets/IMAGESDIRECTORY".
But upon export, the device showed the directory instead resolved to "app:/assets/Imagesdirectory", therefore making the call to IMAGESDIRECTORY invalid.

Oddly, looking for "Imagesdirectory" works for both the PC and the device without changing folder layout and names.

Looks like I've been Gotcha'd - remember never to give directories names in all caps...